# Website hack line appearing on wordpress homepage

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Helping a friend's company with their website. They have a random bit of code appearing on a bar near the top of what looks to be just on the homepage:

http://snakeoilcocktail.com/

The line is here according to the source:

```
<div class='dc'>You take that to bank:<a href="http://www.indianainvestmentwatch.com/">same day loans</a>. Buy there a <a href="http://www.rival-usa.com/">atv armor set</a></div>
```

I used a plugin to do a String check to find out where the line is but I can't see where it's located to edit it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: best option is restoring de most recent back up

Comment: you could try to export the database using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/   Then do a search for any reference to the malware and delete it.  After you could create a new database on the server and change the reference to that database in the wp_config  keep in mind username and password will be different as well.    NOTE: back everything up before doing any of this.  Make a copy of your current DB and your current wp_config etc.  | make sure you update all plugins and WP itself.

Comment: This is for sure a security issue. Best solution is to backup everything and begin updating.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's some malware injected on the site. In the top navigation under "Beverage Catering and Event Mixology" there's what looks like some malicious JS code that's adding a div with a class of "dc". Not sure what your setup is, but I'd advise checking into this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/sucuri-scanner/

It'll tell you if any of the core Wordpress files have been hacked, or if it recognizes any files that aren't part of WP.

They have a free quick scanner, check this out: https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/snakeoilcocktail.com/

Revolution Slider is a big risk :) (Note the comment on Sucuri) It's supposedly been patched but they ran into a huge security issue where thousands of WP sites were infected. Happened to a couple of sites I took over as well - I completely removed it.

In other words, if you have to keep the Revolution Slider plugin, update it ASAP. It introduces a vulnerability that allows hackers to upload arbitrary files to your site - bad news. They often upload something that gives them read access to the wp-config.php file so they can get into the database as well. (http://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/35431/cyber-crime/revslider-plugin-vulnerable.html)

Answer (score 1):

It has to be somewhere! So either one of your plugins is outputting that code or it has been hacked into your theme.

First, try to deactivate all the plugins one after each other to find out if a plugin causes that issue. If that doesn't help, you may need to go through each file in the theme until you found the target. Also notice that the code could look different in a file than the code which you have posted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your website must gave been infected with a `malware/adware` of some sort. This usually happens when you are using a free hosting service. Check whether your friend is using a free hosting service to host his website. Some of those providers inject advertising content into free hosted websites to make revenue.

If this is not the case,

1. **Restore** to previous backup
2. **Disable any plug-ins** used on the website
3. **Check through the code** for any suspicious lines.
4. Delete all the files on the web server if possible and try **re-uploading** 
   the source files.
5. **Migrate** to a hosting provider such as goDaddy, AWS etc for security of 
   your website.